# How to model different types of forms for different requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I'm having a hard time finding information that applies to my situation.  I'm trying to model a request system.  A user can submit a request and each request has a different set of fields.  A request will be of one type and one sub type.  Each request type will have a set of fields specific to that type.  Another set of fields will be specific to the request's sub type.  Here is an example:

- Request

  - Permit (Request Type)

    - Permit General Fields (Request Type = Permit)

      - Permit 1
      - Permit 2
      - Permit 3
      - Plumbing (Permit Sub Type)

        - Plumbing 1
        - Plumbing 2
        - Plumbing 3
      - Electrical (Permit Sub Type)

        - Electrical 1
        - Electrical 2
        - Electrical 3
  - Inspection (Request Type)

    - Inspection General Fields (Request Type = Inspection)

      - Inspection 1
      - Inspection 2
      - Inspection 3
      - Building (Inspection Sub Type)

        - Building 1
        - Building 2
        - Building 3
      - Occupancy (Inspection Sub Type)

        - Occupancy 1
        - Occupancy 2
        - Occupancy 3

Also, when a user logs in they should be able to view all of their requests in a list. *I think this rules out Polymorphism*

I've considered the following so far

### STI

Based on what I've read, I should not use STI if there are only a few fields that overlap, which would be the case here.  The questionnaires will vary significantly based on the request type

### Polymorphism

I don't think i'm looking for a request model to belong to the different type of questionnaire models or a questionnaire model to belong to different request models.  If my understanding is correct, I won't be able to display all request types in a list.

### Each Request Type is it's own model

Doesn't seem practical to do it this way and how would I consolidate them when a User wants to see all of their requests?  EmploymentRequest, InspectionRequest

### STI w/Hstore

I've branched my code to try this out.  This seems like a good option, but one thing concerns me.  If I know for a specific request type I will always have the same set of general fields, it seems like I should be using defined columns in my table to store these general fields.  But, if I defined fields in the table per request type I would end up with a lot of empty columns per record and this is not good STI.

What are your thoughts on STI w/Hstore?  Have I looked at all of my possibilities?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance for your time and feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on something similar. I have found that the surveyor gem is currently not up to date, and has not been maintained for a little while.

My solution has been:
A user creates new instances (requests)
A questionnaire belongs to an instance and has many questions
Answers belong to an instance and to a question

In this way, users can take any number of questionnaires, and specific questionnaires can be developed for specific request categories.

A great way to achieve your different types of sub-items is by using nested forms. Look into the cocoon gem as a quick way to get into this: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon. There also is a railscast on the issue, but it is outdated.

Comment: Jelle - Thanks for your feedback.  I've ruled out the surveyor option based on your feedback.  I'd like to see if there are any other options out there before going down the question/answer route.  I've also added more detail and an example to my posting.

Comment: hi,you can do this kind of things with my suggestion, using nested forms.See my updated answer.

Comment: Jelle - Let me branch my code and give your suggestion a try.  Thanks.